# Creating record in database not working properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating an instance of a friendship between two users. When I create it in the rails console everything works as planned, however, when I actually create the friendship through the site the status column is left blank. If anyone can tell me why it would be really appreciated.

here is the model I have:

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :status, :accepted_at

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"

  def self.request(user,friend)
    unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user: user, friend: friend)
      transaction do
        create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
        create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
      end
    end
  end

  def self.accept(user,friend)
    transaction do
      accepted_at = Time.now
      accept_one_side(user,friend,accepted_at)
      accept_one_side(friend,user,accepted_at)
    end
  end

  def self.accept_one_side(user,friend,accepted_at)
    request = Friendship.where("user_id = #{user.id} AND friend_id = #{friend.id}")
    request.update_all(:status => 'accepted', :accepted_at => accepted_at)
  end
end
```

and this is my controller

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    friend = User.where(email: params[:friend_email]).first
    Friendship.request(current_user,friend)
    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
  end

  def friendship_params
    params.require(:friendship).permit(:friend_email)
  end
end
```

Comment: `Friendship` model has `attr_accessor :status` - `status` looks like a virtual attribute. Do you have a column called `status` ?

Comment: Yeah i have a status column, but it is only set to pending/requested when i create the friendship from the command line. Is that to do with the attr_accessor then?

Comment: Yes, why do you have `attr_accessor :status` ? When you have a column named as `status`, ActiveRecord already creates getter setter methods for it.

Comment: Thanks alot that solved it. So when i added the accessor did that overwrite the methods that active_record had created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Friendship` model has `attr_accessor :status`, which overrides the default getter setter methods provided by `ActiveRecord` for your `status` column.